# Hide scrollbar when scrolling listview programmatically?

Tags: android, android-listview, scrollbar

I made a chat application and have Chat Activity in it.
To display messages in dialog-like style I use ListView.

When I receive or send message to chat I need ListView to scroll down to it's end. Now I doing it with

```
chatView.smoothScrollToPosition(chatAdapter.getCount());
```

But when listview scrolls down it shows an animated vertical scrollbar.
However. I want to display the vertical scrollbar when a user scrolls the list by himself (using finger) and NOT show the scrollbar when I do it programmatically.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Thanks! English is not my native language and, unfortunately, I have some problems with it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you scroll the list programmatically, do this:

```
myListView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

After, do this:

```
myListView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

This will hide / show the scrollbar when (don't) you want it.

Comment: I've already tried it. It doesen't work because myListView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true); calls faster that scrolling animation actually ends.

Comment: @udenfox, there are various ways of detecting scrolling in a ListView, which you should investigate. These methods work even if the list is scrolled programmatically.

Comment: detecting scrolling looks like crutch. I wonder there is any other way to solve that problem.

Comment: @udenfox but it should work. `onScrollStateChanged(..)` + `onScrollListener` will tell you when scrolling has stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:scrollbars="none"`in `ListView`

It will only hide the scrollbars keeping the horizontal or vertical scrolling as it is.